# No sé ve bien mi background-image de mi div (responsive)

Tags: html, css, imagen, responsive, scss

Estoy teniendo un problema para poner de fondo una imagen en un div.

Mi imagen tiene 496px x 421px.
En el html tengo esto (Ignoren las etiquetas de angular) :

---

```
<div class="body">
    <!--Componentes y codigo de angular-->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo-grassi"></div>
        <!--Componentes y codigo de angular-->
    </div>
    <!--Componentes y codigo de angular-->
</div>
```

---

Dentro del div con clase "logo-grassi" y "header" aplico los estilos css que son los siguientes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px 32px;

        position: static;
        left: 0px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .logo-grassi {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        left: 15%;
        top: 25%;
        background-image: url("./../../../../../assets/images/splash.svg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    
    }
}
```

Se muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: Muestra en el navegador del código]

---

Si cambio en el width y hight los porcentajes por los pixeles de la imagen pasa esto:

```
.logo-grassi{
    ...
    width: 496px;
    height: 421px;
    ...
}
```

[image: La imagen como espero que se muestre]

En este caso, la pantalla se muestra como espero **LA IMAGEN ESTA DISEÑADA PARA ESTA MEDIDA DE PANTALLA (1920px de ancho)**
El problema es que cuando achico la pantalla, como el div tiene un tamaño fijo de 496px, eso no se achica y queda feo.
[image: Imagen cuando achico la pantalla]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución, solo le quité la propiedad de `background-size: cover;`
y ahora se muestra correctamente.

Comment: Amigo, bien pudiste editar tu pregunta para añadir este comentario en lugar de ponerlo en el apartado de respuestas...

Comment: Pensé que ahí iba mejor porque muestra la solución. Ahí agrego la solución en mi pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: @ang3les96, lo que hizo el OP (autor de la pregunta) es correcto, recuerda que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_, por lo tanto no debe editar su pregunta para mostrar lo que le fue útil. Por otra parte, Miqueas: no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: @padaleiana lo que había ocurrido es que solo añadió la respuesta sin algún indicio de haberlo solucionado, como suele suceder cuando algunos usuarios hacen algún cambio que no reflejan en la pregunta pero sí añadiendo una respuesta y resulta ser una actualización, por lo que hice el comentario anterior, sin embargo, considero que aunque sea repetitivo, agregar que encontró la solución adjunta a la respuesta que brindó sería más sencillo para ayudar a futuros usuarios que tal vez tendrían el mismo problema a dar con la solución que el autor de la pregunta pudo solventar por sí mismo. Saludos.

Comment: De hecho, lo hizo, solo que le faltó especificar que eso resolvió el problema descrito en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunas modificaciones basándome en el código, hiciste. En este ejemplo la imagen que utilizo es de 450px `https://picsum.photos/450` y tuve que quitar el `media query` para que el ejemplo se ejecute.

Puedes englobar todo es un solo media; `@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {`.

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.rigth {
    padding: 10px;
}

.logo-grassi {
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/450");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
<div class="header">

<div class="logo-grassi"></div>

<div class="rigth">
<h1>Te damos la bienvenida</h1>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```